# Alert Not Showing Front in StageWebview

Tags: flex4, alert, stagewebview

I am using StageWebview to display my content in flex 4.6. When i open alert box it always showing background of the StaegeWebview. How to display alert box in front of StageWebview.

Answer (score 2):

One tricky solution for your issue, when ever you want to show the alert just get the snapshot of the `StaegeWebview` using this `drawViewPortToBitmapData` method and then add that `Bitmap` to the view hierarchy. remove the `StaegeWebview` and latter after removing the dialog add it back again.